# Why django contains a lot of '__init__.py'?

Tags: python, django, module

Many directories in a django project contain a `__init__.py` and I think it will be used as initialization for something. Where is this `__init__.py` used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python doesn't take every subdirectory of every directory in `sys.path` to necessarily be a *package*: only those with a file called `__init__.py`. Consider the following shell session:

```
$ mkdir adir
$ echo 'print "hello world"' > adir/helo.py
$ python -c 'import adir.helo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named adir.helo
$ touch adir/__init__.py
$ python -c 'import adir.helo'
hello world
```

See? With just directory `adir` and module `helo.py` in it, the attempt to `import adir.helo` fails. If `__init__.py` also exists in `adir`, **then** Python knows that `adir` is a package, and therefore the import succeeds.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is not clear. What exactly are you asking?

The file `__init__.py` is there so your folder can be defined as [a package](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/Packages.html), which lets you do things like:

```
from myapp.models import Something
```